# How to get Nexus S, Version 4.0.4 (IceCreamSandwich), to register as a device on a Windows 7?

Tags: android, windows, device, device-driver

I'm trying to find a way to my Window 7 machine to recognize the Nexus S phone I am trying to plug in, it seems that my computer cannot locate the appropriate driver so that it can recognize this phone (it fails to update the driver automatically when I open up Windows Device Manager and select the Nexus S and click Update Driver).  What driver do I actually need and where can I get it?

Otherwise, why isn't the Windows 7 recognizing this phone?  It says on the phone "USB connected" and "USB debugging connected", so the phone seems to think it's connecting to the computer.

My Goal:  To be able to look through the Nexus S folders that appear once you get it as a registered device b/c I need to figure out how to manually flash an image onto the phone (visit the following link to another question I am trying to figure out the answer to that this question impacts: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24397/has-anyone-flashed-an-android-build-i-e-a-crespo-build-onto-a-nexus-s-phone-m)

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for the Android SA site: http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know about this, I will duly direct future questions there then as applicable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for what you want: http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: Thank you, at least that's something I can try.  However, I have gone through downloading the source code from REPO for platform development, shouldn't have those drivers have come with that too?  I have been referring to these directions:  http://source.android.com/source/building.html

Comment: Whenever I work with different phones, I usually have to download device specific drivers. Why they bundled it like this beats me. But hopefully you are able to connect to your phone now.